# Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 4.2.0 92AC1r00M3X6cxD012AChG Message can't be accepted "

Tags: exception, symfony-1.4, sendmail, swiftmailer

i would like to send email from action symfony 1.4 but i have this Swift_TransportException:

Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 4.2.0 92AC1r00M3X6cxD012AChG Message can't be accepted 
"

Comment: Have you got anything else in your apache log files ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any further info on your apache error log ?

Your SMTP response code of 451 indicates that you're connecting ok to your server but this one is not being able to process your message. Are there any limitations with your account ?

The "4.2.0" bit could indicate a Timeout communication problem.

Are you having this problem consistently ? Or has it just stopped working ?

Try the following :

-> "Message can't be accepted" clue :
 In case there's a problem with your message try with a simpler message (one liner, no attachements, just the simplest of messages)

-> account clue :
 In case there's a problem with your account (spamfilter, or some other limitation) try with a different account.

-> network / infrastructure problems :
Try a different mail server. (You can use something like mailchimp, mailjet, sendgrid, or some other third party email provider. See a [comparative list here](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/transactional-emailing-providers-mailjet-sendgrid-critsend).)

Comment: Then you want to try different things to try and narrow the problem down. Try a different message... Try a different account... Try a different SMTP server.

Comment: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mail.yahoo.com [Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #0]

Comment: ssl is not enabled ? see you php.ini file. or do an  *echo phpinfo()* Are you on linux ? windows ?

Comment: i'm on linux and ssl is enabled

Comment: try 'ssl' (in lowercase) . Also have you tried 'tls' ?  Also do a *var_dump ( stream_get_transports() );* and see what's listed.